# Ruby Metaprogramming: Dynamically defining method based on child instance attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a presenter base class which is supposed to wrap an ActiveRecord object.

```
class BasePresenter
  def initialize object
    @object = object
  end

  def method_missing(*args, &block)
    @object.send(*args, &block)
  end

  def self.wrap collection
    collection.map { |item| new item }
  end
end
```

For each child class, I would like to be able to dynamically define a method based on a child attribute at initialization, so a ListPresenter like:

```
class ListPresenter < BasePresenter
end
```

should respond to `list_id` with the wrapped List object's id.

How would I do that short of defining it on every child class? I've tried the following in `def initialize(object)`, both of which do not work.
Would prefer to avoid `eval` based approaches if possible as I hear it's a code smell.

Class approach (adds the method to BasePresenter, not the child classes)

```
self.class.send(:define_method, "#{object.class.name.underscore}_id") do
  @object.id
end
```

Metaclass approach (unable to access instance variables `object` or `@object`):

```
class << self
  define_method "#{@object.class.name.underscore}_id" do
    @object.id
  end
end
```

Comment: When you say that these don't work, what happens?

Comment: @FrederickCheung: Added clarification on what happened with previous approaches.

Comment: @fylooi: What is the reason for wanting to prefix the `id` with the model name (i.e. `list_id`), rather than just delegating `id` to the model?

Comment: And where are you putting these calls to define_method?

Comment: @Drenmi: Not a concrete use case, was thinking along the lines of redefining a model attribute while keeping the original one available. Also figured it might come in handy to conditionally decorate certain types of child models. 
@FrederickCheung: In `def initialize object` after the object assignment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Class#inherited`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Class.html#method-i-inherited) hook to dynamically add a method whenever sub-class inherits BasePresenter.

```
class BasePresenter
  def self.inherited(sub_klass)
    sub_klass.send(:define_method, "#{sub_klass.name.underscore.split("_")[0...-1].join("_")}_id") do
      instance_variable_get("@object").id
    end
  end
end


class ListPresenter < BasePresenter
end

# Sending a rails model object below
l = ListPresenter.new(User.first)
l.list_id #=> 1
```

Comment: Why the need for `.split("_")[0...-1].join("_")` though?

Comment: `"ListPresenter".underscore` #=> "list_presenter". I am extracting just "list". Similarly `"FooBarPresenter".underscore`  #=> "foo_bar_presenter" where you would want "foo_bar_id". Hence `.split("_")[0...-1].join("_") `. Assuming all sub_klasses have `Presenter` suffixed in it's name.

Comment: Ahhh. I wanted the `@object`s class actually. No problems, will be trivial since this gives me access to `@object`.

Comment: oh. yes, you can easily retrieve that inside that method and do the needful

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you have a look at [`Class#inherited`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Class.html#method-i-inherited).

You can define this method in your base class and it irate over the inheriting classes' methods...

I'll probably edit this once I'm sitting at my computer, but it's quite straightforward.