# Access Rails class const from within extended relation module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, constants, mixins

I'm having an inheritance/mixin brain fart and was wondering if someone felt like enlightening me.

I use query classes throughout my app to encapsulate complex, role-specific queries. For instance there may be a PostQuery class and a PhotoQuery class.

I also have a base query class that exposes generic relation extensions for things such as pagination.

The problem I'm having is that I want to access constants that are defined in the including class from the base relation methods, but no matter what combination of inheritance/inclusion I've tried, its eluding me.

I've posted a simple gist below with a simplified broken example. Cheers.

https://gist.github.com/uberllama/9e69529b0d835902f33d

Comment: Does it work to just use a class method, instead of the constant?

Comment: No, the extended methods in the BaseQuery module can't seem to access anything outside of itself.

Answer (score 0):

Convoluted workaround based on a question i had earlier - use `self.inherited(sub_klass)` in the base class to call `sub_klass.const_get`. Then use this to `send` `define_method` to `sub_klass` with the subclass's constants.

[Ruby Metaprogramming: Dynamically defining method based on child instance attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875357/ruby-metaprogramming-dynamically-defining-method-based-on-child-instance-attrib)

```
class BaseQuery

  ALLOWED_SORT_ATTRS = []

  def initialize(relation)
    @relation = relation.extending(Scopes)
  end

  def self.inherited(sub_klass)
    sub_klass.send(:define_method, 'allowed_sort_attrs') do
      sub_klass.const_get(:ALLOWED_SORT_ATTRS)
    end
    sub_klass.send(:define_method, 'scoped') do
      Scope.new(sub_klass)
    end
  end

  class Scope
    def initialize(klass)
      @klass = klass 
    end

    def sorted(sort_param, sort_direction)
      if klass.allowed_sort_attrs.include(sort_param)
        order("#{sort_param} #{sort_direction}")
      else
        order("id DESC")
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: I made PostQuery inherit from BaseQuery and tried your technique, but it actually ended up blowing away the const altogether. I updated the gist: https://gist.github.com/uberllama/9e69529b0d835902f33d#comment-1443773

Comment: Looking at your gist - is the constant named 'ALLOWED_SORT_ATTRS' or 'ALLOWED_ATTR_NAMES'?

Comment: Was just a typo. Corrected.

Comment: Worked after i defined the constant on `BaseQuery`. This addresses the first part about accessing constants from the base class. I would suggest you use a separate class for the scope, and initialize that within the child class to get access.

Comment: Revised answer to include `Scope`. `sub_klass.scoped.sorted` works for this implementation.

Comment: Did say it was convoluted. Was a fun exercise. :)

Answer (score 0):

For now, I've decided to just interpolate the current relation within the methods to get at the const.

```
def sorted
  allowed_attr_names = "#{klass}Query".constantize.const_get(:ALLOWED_ATTR_NAMES)
end
```

In this case, if I'm within a Post relation, it'll retrieve `PostQuery::ALLOWED_ATTR_NAMES`